# Docker - Laravel App Not Running and Not Error

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-sail

The container stands up and doesn't give any error but also doesn't work. When I try another app that has the same sub-core of the app, I see that it works successfully. The problem is in this app, I'm sure now.

I am leaving some necessary files below. I have no idea what the problem is. Thank you if anyone can help.

supervisord.conf file

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
user=root
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid

[program:php]
command=/usr/bin/php -d variables_order=EGPCS /var/www/html/artisan octane:start --watch --server=swoole --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
user=sail
environment=LARAVEL_SAIL="1"
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:laravel-horizon]
command=/usr/bin/php -d variables_order=EGPCS /var/www/html/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=sail
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

compose file

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        container_name: Laravel
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-8000}:8000'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        container_name: MySql
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - "/var/lib/mysql"
        networks:
            - sail
    phpmyadmin:
        image: 'phpmyadmin:latest'
        container_name: PhpMyAdmin
        ports:
            - 8081:80
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
            MYSQL_ROOT_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        networks:
            - sail
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        container_name: Redis
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
```

Docker Desktop Image

[image]

Comment: You say your application doesn't start up successfully, but then you show an image file at the end; are there text-format error logs you can show instead of the image?  How do you know it's not starting up?  One downside of supervisord is that you won't see the application logs; can you remove supervisord from this stack and run the program directly in a container?  You have a bind mount that hides the image's `/var/www/html` directory and replaces it with local files; does deleting this improve the situation at all?